# Can I write the files in Application's document directory in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I was creating iPad application to view book and it's kind of publishing book. End user can able to download the book to view in offline mode. So I am writing the entire book content (PNG and XML) into application’s document directory.  Size of the book content is greater than 500MB. Due to size of the memory, the apple store will reject the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write however much you want in there (Documents directory). The only hung you need to pay attention to is flagging which contents should not be sync'd to iTunes/iCloud during back ups. That will get you refused.

Please check out this document from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

The basic idea is only user settings and created content should be backed up, any content that can be downloaded again should not be backed up.